# ' "length": 147, "severity": "ERROR" ' error while using pg and node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am using node.js and postgresql. On my local I can create records from the admin but on production I am getting the following error:

```
{ "name": "error", "length": 147, "severity": "ERROR"
```

I am unable to find the reason for the same.

I am calling the following API for saving records:

```
saveTopic = function (req, res) {
  logsInConsole(req);

  db.Topic
    .create({
      topic_name: req.body.topic_name,
      topic_category: req.body.topic_category
    })
    .success(function(result){
      res.redirect('/topics');
    }).error(function(error){
        res.send('Failed to save Topic. Something went wrong. Here is the error: ');
        res.send(error);
    });
};
```

So when I try to create the record, it redirects to `'/saveTopic'` url where I can see the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log say?

Comment: @KouberSaparev In my logs I can see the INSERT query is run but on the UI I get the above error

Comment: Any chance to see the complete 147 characters of the error itself? The thing you posted looks like a truncated JSON object.

Comment: @KouberSaparev I know it looks abrupt but actually this is all that I can see :(

Comment: Without at least the `code` from the error object it's not really possible to isolate the error. Where are you seeing this truncated output?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have edited my post now stating where I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

There was duplicate primary key issue due to some records were manually inserted in the beginning on the server. So I emptied the table and reinserted the records and it works fine now. Thanks for your help guys. Hope this helps someone.